# Model binding with angularjs and mvc4 not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to angularjs.My problem is simple.I have a controller in javascript which displays candidate result and I want to display details of the candidate.

```
//For displaying Candidate List
 var Listcandidates = $resource('/api/Candidate', {}, { update: { method: 'GET' } });

    $scope.candidateslist = [];
    $scope.candidate = {};
    Listcandidates.query(function (data) {
        $scope.candidateslist.length = 0;
        angular.forEach(data, function (CandidateData) {
            $scope.candidateslist.push(CandidateData);
        })

    });
//For displaying candidate details
 $scope.editCandidate = function (id) {
        var Canid = String(id);
        $location.path("/editCandidate/" + id);

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/Candidate', params: { Candidateid: Canid } }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.candidate = data;



        });


    }
```

EditCandidate.html

```
<div class="control-group" >

     <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="candidate.name" class="span3" />
</div>
```

I have given alert in editcandidate and showing data properly but in EditCandidate.html it cannot getting the model.Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using another controller.